# Where the hardcoded values come from in hashing / compression / encoding algorithms

Tags: algorithm, hash, workflow

I'm wondering how things like [these](https://github.com/bitwiseshiftleft/sjcl/blob/master/core/scrypt.js) get decided:

```
for (var i = rounds; i > 0; i -= 2) {
  x[ 4] ^= R(x[ 0]+x[12], 7);  x[ 8] ^= R(x[ 4]+x[ 0], 9);
  x[12] ^= R(x[ 8]+x[ 4],13);  x[ 0] ^= R(x[12]+x[ 8],18);
  x[ 9] ^= R(x[ 5]+x[ 1], 7);  x[13] ^= R(x[ 9]+x[ 5], 9);
  x[ 1] ^= R(x[13]+x[ 9],13);  x[ 5] ^= R(x[ 1]+x[13],18);
  x[14] ^= R(x[10]+x[ 6], 7);  x[ 2] ^= R(x[14]+x[10], 9);
  x[ 6] ^= R(x[ 2]+x[14],13);  x[10] ^= R(x[ 6]+x[ 2],18);
  x[ 3] ^= R(x[15]+x[11], 7);  x[ 7] ^= R(x[ 3]+x[15], 9);
  x[11] ^= R(x[ 7]+x[ 3],13);  x[15] ^= R(x[11]+x[ 7],18);
  x[ 1] ^= R(x[ 0]+x[ 3], 7);  x[ 2] ^= R(x[ 1]+x[ 0], 9);
  x[ 3] ^= R(x[ 2]+x[ 1],13);  x[ 0] ^= R(x[ 3]+x[ 2],18);
  x[ 6] ^= R(x[ 5]+x[ 4], 7);  x[ 7] ^= R(x[ 6]+x[ 5], 9);
  x[ 4] ^= R(x[ 7]+x[ 6],13);  x[ 5] ^= R(x[ 4]+x[ 7],18);
  x[11] ^= R(x[10]+x[ 9], 7);  x[ 8] ^= R(x[11]+x[10], 9);
  x[ 9] ^= R(x[ 8]+x[11],13);  x[10] ^= R(x[ 9]+x[ 8],18);
  x[12] ^= R(x[15]+x[14], 7);  x[13] ^= R(x[12]+x[15], 9);
  x[14] ^= R(x[13]+x[12],13);  x[15] ^= R(x[14]+x[13],18);
}
```

That is, these are a bunch of specific hardcoded values. I'm wondering what goes into making such decisions as to figure this out as a solution. I'd be interested to know if:

1. It is done by trial and error in some way.
2. If not, if there is some method to the madness.

This is another example:

```
// Gamma0
var gamma0xh = w[(i-15) * 2];
var gamma0xl = w[(i-15) * 2 + 1];
var gamma0h =
  ((gamma0xl << 31) | (gamma0xh >>> 1)) ^
  ((gamma0xl << 24) | (gamma0xh >>> 8)) ^
   (gamma0xh >>> 7);
var gamma0l =
  ((gamma0xh << 31) | (gamma0xl >>> 1)) ^
  ((gamma0xh << 24) | (gamma0xl >>> 8)) ^
  ((gamma0xh << 25) | (gamma0xl >>> 7));

// Gamma1
var gamma1xh = w[(i-2) * 2];
var gamma1xl = w[(i-2) * 2 + 1];
var gamma1h =
  ((gamma1xl << 13) | (gamma1xh >>> 19)) ^
  ((gamma1xh << 3)  | (gamma1xl >>> 29)) ^
   (gamma1xh >>> 6);
var gamma1l =
  ((gamma1xh << 13) | (gamma1xl >>> 19)) ^
  ((gamma1xl << 3)  | (gamma1xh >>> 29)) ^
  ((gamma1xh << 26) | (gamma1xl >>> 6));
```

There are many other examples of this in [different](https://github.com/bitwiseshiftleft/sjcl/blob/master/core/sha512.js) hashing algorithms and encoding things.

Comment: If it's done properly, these things are decided by someone with deep knowledge of [finite field arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field_arithmetic).

Comment: Darn there's no JS modules on it :). Wikipedia makes it sound like there's not too much to it, wondering if there is an awesome textbook or paper explaining the full scope. I'd say this is pretty much the answer. But it would be good to add how they go about picking a value, even with just a basic example/demo.

Comment: It's not a finite field thing because you get a 1-1 transformation regardless of the constants (you can construct the inverse similarly to a Feistel network). The constants are chosen for good mixing/resistance to differential cryptanalysis/probably several other considerations that I don't know about because I'm not a crypto expert.